# Minimize variance subject to constraint using eigenvector and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

The following is an interview question.

> Given three random variables $X,Y,Z$ and $a,b,c,$ find the minimum value of $Var(aX+bY+cZ)$ subject to the constraint $a^2+b^2+c^2 = 1.$

I solved the problem using Lagrangian multiplier. But the interviewer said it is too tedious and time consuming as we need to solve a lot of equations. In this case, there are $4$.

He suggested the following:

Observe that 
$$Var(aX+bY+cZ) = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
Var(X) & Cov(X,Y) & Cov(X,Z) \\
Cov(X,Y) & Var(Y) & Cov(Y,Z) \\
Cov(X,Z) & Cov(Y,Z) & Var(Z) \\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
a \\ 
b\\ 
c
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Since all symmetric matrix is diagonalizable, so 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
Var(X) & Cov(X,Y) & Cov(X,Z) \\
Cov(X,Y) & Var(Y) & Cov(Y,Z) \\
Cov(X,Z) & Cov(Y,Z) & Var(Z) \\
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
- & v_1 & - \\
- & v_2 & - \\
- & v_3 & - 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
| & | & |  \\
v_1 & v_2 & v_3\\
| & | & |
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3$ are eigenvalues of the covariance matrix with eigenvectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ respectively.

The interviewer said that from here, it should be easy to see that the minimum occurs at the eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue.

But I do not see how to deduce it from equations above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Sigma$ be the $3\times 3$ covariance matrix. It can be written as $\Sigma = V\Lambda V^\top$ where $\Lambda$ is diagonal with entries $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$, and where the columns of $V$ are orthonormal eigenvectors (i.e. $V$ is an orthogonal matrix). (Note that in your question, you or your interviewer mixed up $V$ and $V^\top$.)

You want to find the vector $u$
that minimizes $u^\top \Sigma u$
subject to $\|u\|^2 = 1$.

Consider the similar problem of minimizing $w^\top \Lambda w$ subject to $\|w\|^2 = 1$. Since $w^\top \Lambda w = \lambda_1 w_1^2 + \lambda_2 w_2^2 + \lambda_3 w_3^2$, you can check that the best choice of $w$ is
$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ if $\lambda_1$ is the smallest eigenvalue, 
$\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ if $\lambda_2$ is the smallest eigenvalue,  and so on. And the minimized value of $w^\top \Lambda w$ is the smallest eigenvalue.

Let us return to the original problem of minimizing $u^\top \Sigma u$.
This objective function can be written as $u^\top V \Sigma V^\top u$.
Note that $\|V^\top u\| = \|u\|$ because $V$ is an orthogonal matrix. So we can reduce the problem to the second type (with the "change of variables" $w=  V^\top u$) and see that this problem also has minimum value equal to the smallest eigenvalue.

Comment: Based on Wikipedia of diagonalization, the matrix whose columns are eigenvectors should be the last instead of first?

Comment: @Idonknow I think what I have written is correct. You may be conflating $\Sigma = V \Lambda V^\top$ and $V^\top \Sigma V = \Lambda$.

Comment: Is there a mathematical way to show that the nest choice of $\omega$ is the unit vector where thee nonzero entry corresponds to the smallest eigenvalue?

Comment: Since $w_1^2 + \cdots + w_3^2 = 1$, you can see that $\lambda_1 w_1^2 + \cdots + \lambda_3 w_3^2$ is a weighted average of $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$, and thus is always as large as the minimum eigenvalue. Since you can achieve exactly the smallest eigenvalue with the right choice of $w$, that must be the minimum. Succinctly, $\lambda_1 w_1^2 + \cdots + \lambda_3 w_3^2 \ge \lambda_{\min}(w_1^2 + \cdots + w_3^2) = \lambda_{\min}$.

Comment: In your last line, you wrote that $\|V^T u\| = \|u\|$ because $V$ is orthogonal. Does it mean that all orthogonal matrices are isometry (distance-preserving function)?

Comment: @Idonknow Yes. $\|V^\top u\|^2 = u^\top V V^\top u = u^\top u = \|u\|^2$ because $VV^\top = I$.